# Tomcat7 not load welcome page in my Java Web app

Tags: java, tomcat

I have simple JavaWeb app.

For debuging i am using `jetty` on my laptop (in `netbeans`). If i run the app - Normally it works - welcome page run perfect. I can go to `localhost:8080` for my "index" page.

When i run the app on my `tomcat` vehicle. **Tomtcat not open** "welcome index page".

Why? Where can be a problem?

In my `web.xml` is:

```
.
.
<display-name>MYAPP</display-name>
<description>basic application.</description>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WEB-INF/pages/home/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
.
.
```

Other pages on tomcat work normaly. For example `www.mypage.com/about` run perfect. I think, its problem in `web.xml`.

Thank you for your advice!

Error in tomcat:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

Comment: what URL you are trying on browser ?

Comment: @AnandDwivedi Sorry anand, I can't post there my url. I add to post error code of tomcat.

Comment: Are you using `www.mypage.com/index.html`?

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper No, I haven't file index.html there is a "servlet".

Comment: did you try with localhost:8080/yourapp/welcomefileName ?

Comment: Then give the servlet path instead of `index.html`

Comment: most probably your about.jsps are outside the web-inf folder . If possible  move your welcome page outside web-inf . If you can not, create a welcome file outside web-inf and forward it to the proper one. I think It's security feature, that you can not access content inside web-inf directly, it has to go through servlet

Comment: index.html file put inside the project Folder not in WEB-INF .

Comment: I make a test `index.html` page and change `<welcome-file>` in my `web.xml` to `index.html` and is same problem `HTTP Status 404 `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by inserting this `/WEB-INF/pages/home/index.html`

in place of `WEB-INF/pages/home/index.html`